# Single quote character in query string causes SQL injection

Tags: security, asp-classic

I was just wondering if adding a single quote mark to an embedded query string parameter in a hard coded SQL query could cause a SQL injection error? As you can see after the `@docNum` parameter I am using both the percent and single quote characters. Somewhere in my code something is causing the error. Now if I were to only use a single percent character `%` instead of both the `%` and the single quote character `%'` unlike in the StringBuilder appended line below would this the stop the error from occurring?

```
sb.Append("AND docNumTCN LIKE  thumbsdown @docNum%' " );
```

Comment: Sure this is Classic ASP? Looks like ASP.NET. You will probably need to encode single quotes (as two single quotes).

Comment: Why are you using a % and apostrophe in the first place?  The clue's in the parameter's property - `ParameterName`. I'd never use symbols like this - bad design.

Comment: You also need to include the database technology you're using, as the `StringBuilder` string you've got there is surely an error waiting to happen.

Comment: What's a SQL injection _error_? I think you're confusing two separate issues. There's a SQL error, which means that there's a problem with your syntax. And there's SQL Injection which is a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct here, I suspect you're trying to look for a document number that can be `Like` another. Perhaps what you're trying to achieve is this:

```vb
sb.Append("AND docNumTCN LIKE '%' + @docNum + '%' ")
```

The confusing part is the `thumbsdown` field that you've got in there.